# Replacing <title>Welcome</title> will not work

Tags: html, powershell, replace

I have an aspx file I'm trying to update with powershell 1.0. The file looks like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
```

I use:

```
(Get-Content "C:\documents and settings\login.aspx") | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "<title>Welcome!</title>","<title>Welcome! Warning...</title>"} | Set-Content "C:\documents and settings\login.aspx"
```

and it does nothing.

However, I use:

```
(Get-Content "C:\documents and settings\login.aspx") | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "<title>Welcome!","<title>Welcome! Warning..."} | Set-Content "C:\documents and settings\login.aspx"
```

and it replaces it but obviously the wrong way:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Welcome! Warning...</title></title>
```

What's going on here? I want my first example to work

Comment: With the code you have written I am unable to replicate the problem. The first example works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content "C:\documents and settings\login.aspx" |
```

is reading each line of file and immediately passing it down the pipeline... file is in use, yet you are trying to change the file in the last cmdlet => no good

```
(Get-Content "C:\documents and settings\login.aspx") |
```

You are reading the file, and after finishing that up and then passing each line down the pipeline, which is fine, and you can update the file, because it is not in use

Comment: I don't understand your statement `file is in use, yet....=>no good`. Therefore, that's why I probably don't understand how to fix it?

Comment: No, I thought I did not see () around get-content in the first case and was trying to explain why it would not work without paranthesis. 

I do not see anything wrong with your first statement though.

Comment: OK. Good to know. I'll look more at the code and see what's up. I didn't include all of the code because there's a lot. I thought it had something to do with the part I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error. There was a typo in my original script (not shown here). I wrote it out in similar code for this question for privacy purposes on what I am actually working on. After taking a day off from working on this project, I came back to it and saw the typo. I corrected it and it now works.

Thanks!